# How do you sort bookmarks in Safari alphabetically?

Tags: safari, bookmarks, sorting, ordering

I have a lot of bookmarks in Safari and I would like to sort them alphabetically. It's a pain to do it manually, and I don't seem to find a "Sort alphabetically" menu option.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- open a Finder window and the Safari Bookmarks window
- drag the folder(s) you want sorted from the Safari window to your Desktop
- go to Finder and open each folder, set the view to list view and then close the window
- drag the folder back into Safari’s Bookmarks window Safari will add it
- open the folder in Bookmarks and you will see  your new sorted bookmarks

**Note**: You’ll have duplicates of bookmarks because the old ones are still there. Click on it and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Safari, Apple finally added a context menu entry to sort the contents of bookmark folders. To access it, go to Bookmarks → Edit Bookmarks, then right click on any folder and choose 'Sort by...':

[image]

Unfortunately, this option does not allow to sort folders on top. Instead, [SafariSort](http://www.safarisort.com) may be helpful.